# Random permutation matrix mathematical notation

Tags: matrices, permutations, notation, random

My doubt is about how could I represent this function: `randperm (N, M)` from MATLAB/GNU Octave or `np.random.permutation` from Python in a mathematical notation? I know that $N$, $M$ are about $n$ cols and $m$ rows respectively and I saw in wikipedia that authors represented matrix permutation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix as ${P_{\pi}}_{m,n}$ and I saw in a post here in Stack Exchange Mathematics channel that random variables could be represented as $R_{m,n}$ or $\mathbb{N} \hspace{0.2cm} \cap \hspace{0.2cm} [start, end]: start \in \mathbb{N}, end \in \mathbb{N}$ and $end > start$.

For example how could I describe mathematically this code?

`BS  = B(randperm(size(b,1)),:);`

The code above tends to attribute the shuffled content of $B_{5,2}$ matrix to $BS$ with the same dimension $BS_{5,2}$ where B and BS are matrices.

Example:
Let $B_{5,2}$ a matrix where:
$B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 10\\ 2 & 20 \\ 3 & 30 \\ 4 & 40 \\ 5 & 50 \end{bmatrix}$

So $BS$ will be $BS_{5,2}$ and his values are the shuffled rows from $B$:
$BS = \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 50\\ 2 & 20 \\ 3 & 30 \\ 1 & 10 \\ 4 & 40 \end{bmatrix}$ for example

I use to represent length as $N_{M_{m,n}}$ and size of a matrix as $(M_{m,n})$.

Comment: Hardly understandable. What are you exactly trying to do? Find a notation for a function described by a program? But you aren't describing what it does and it's absolutely not obvious from your post that Octave and Python compute the same thing. Are we supposed to guess your thoughts, check the documentation on several websites or the actual implementation, and guess what you would like as an answer? Also a permutation matrix is not the same thing as a permutation (though it's related).

Comment: Hi @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, I have explained what the code does below the code it shuffles the content of $B$ and attributes the shuffled matrix in $BS$, for example be $B$ a matrix 5 rows and 2 cols with the values: B = [[1 10][2 20][3 30][4 40][5 50] his matrix random permutation is equal BS = [[5 50][2 20][3 30][1 10][4 40] where BS also has 5 rows and 2 cols. Note that only the rows were shuffled but the columns are preserved

Comment: I have tried to check the documentation of some websites and it's still easy to understand what they do, but there aren't any mathematical explanations of them and about random permutation is still possible to find something around the net but nothing involving the mathematics and algebra behind it.

Comment: Then you are shuffling rows, but that is done with $PB$ where $P$ is a permutation matrix. If you compute $BP$, you are shuffling columns. But I fail to see what you expect beyond this. Something like: *"Let $\pi$ be a permutation of $(1,\dots,n)$, $P$ the corresponding permutation matrix, and $C=PB$"* What else?

Comment: No, $B$ is a normal matrix without permutation matrix yet, and $BS$ is the permutation matrix from $B$ with the rows shuffled yes!!

Comment: And as I wrote, permuting rows is equivalent to left-multiply by a permutation matrix. Is it what you are asking for?

Comment: Oh I didn't know that!! And yes, this is what I asked for. Thank you for the help @Jean-ClaudeArbaut!!!!

Comment: Another question @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, for example, when you wrote $\pi$ to be a permutation of $(1,...,n)$ you wanted to say that the cols were permuted? Already that n is the number of cols?

Comment: Right-multiply by a permutation matrix. But take care of you build those permutation matrices, and how they permute row and columns. To apply the same permutation of rows and columns (assuming the matrix is square), you have to compute respectively $PB$ and $BP^T$.